# How long raw, roasted, salted, smoked or dried fish/meat each lasts in the cellar?

Tags: unreal-world

This is about food inventory management/strategy in *Unreal World* (3.20p2). The wiki *cellar* article [states](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Cellar) *raw meat and fish will stay fresh for 3 days without being cooked* and that *all raw and cooked food will last longer if kept in a cellar*; it also adds a little piece of advice: *Maintain different cellars so you could differ this year's food and last year's food.* There is a list of how long a produce lasts whether it's raw, roasted (cooked), salted, smoked or dried. But the [*dried meat*](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Dried_meat) article claims the food lasts close to a whole year when dried, irrespective of being in a cellar or not (see generally [*cookery*](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Cookery_%28Skill%29)).

I want to try to mass fish for as many days straight as possible and then batch dry it to make food waste management predictable. Generally the issue is simply that I don't know exactly since when I've put those things in the cellar and therefore I'm even more unsure how long each will last. This is because stocking the cellar is based on my daily routine...

---

[image]

<sup>*Right-click/open/zoom to see details*: (1) It is [Winter](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Winter_Survival). Early morning I wake up in my [sleeping bunk](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Sleeping_bunk) with elk fur, wearing elk fur [and such](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/203424) so the fireplace having died out is no big deal; I may have breakfast then pick up my [raft](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Raft) and paddle... (2) ...and go check on my three [fishing](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Fishing) nets cast in the rapids yesterday; today there wasn't any fish and I set the nets again. (3) I'd usually do some active fishing with the fine fishing rod I bought some time ago. Follows an inspection of the surroundings as I have a few traps (including [for bears](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Heavy_deadfall_bear_trap)) laid out. I'll also check on whether some of the dry fish next to the cabin is ready for storage, as well as the one being smoked inside; and make more or cook a nice fish soup with the leftovers from the day's catch. We also have lots of wood piled up close to our cabin, and have [split](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Timbercraft_%28Skill%29) a 1000 pieces of firewood. Finally, a look at my cellar (in the house, bottom right) inventory, trying to figure out what's the situation here...</sup>

---

- How long exactly each category food (*raw, roasted, salted,
  smoked, dried*) lasts **in the cellar**?
- Is it a good idea to fish for days and store all the raw fish in the
  cellar, then have all the ropes ready and dry **in bulk** everything?
- What else can I change in my routine/setup to be able to
  **predict** how much food I'll have for how long so that I can tune my
  resource gathering accordingly (i.e. fish less and dedicate more time
  to building items for trading, [hideworking](http://www.unrealworld.fi/wiki/index.php?title=Hideworking_%28Skill%29), or expanding etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cellar, the raw fish will last for 3 days at least, maybe 6. That’s not a bad idea but keep in mind that you can only dry batches of *the same* item (all roach, or bream, or pike, etc). I would focus on larger food items such as pike and trout. I mainly fish so I’m talking about fish lol but this would apply to other meats from hunting too. Happy fishing/hunting/ preserving! :) also, drying is the best method of preservation. Kept in a cellar, I’ve read that it can last for years. Salted and smoked food won’t last as long.